# Redirect users using nginx as a load balancer to save on bandwidth

Tags: redirect, nginx, load-balancing, bandwidth, static-files

I recently purchased 4 servers for my videos to even out the load. I'm currently using nginx as a load balancer but I'm running out of bandwidth.

Is there any way I can redirect users to one of the servers to lower my bandwidth usage and still be able to detect if the server is up?

This is what i'm currently using:

```
upstream videos {
    server xx.xx.xxx.130:8080;
    server xx.xx.xxx.131:8080;
    server xx.xx.xxx.132:8080;
    server xx.xx.xxx.133:8080;
}

proxy_next_upstream error;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://videos;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise on what you're trying to do.. I don't see why changing the config would improve your overall bandwidth.

Comment: I'm trying to redirect users to one of the servers in the videos upstream instead of using the main server as a reverse proxy, so that the main server isn't using up too much bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with weight parameter for bandwith balancing:

```
upstream videos {
    server xx.xx.xxx.130:8080 weight=5; # high bandwith server
    server xx.xx.xxx.131:8080 weight=5; # high bandwith server
    server xx.xx.xxx.132:8080 weight=3; # middle bandwith server
    server xx.xx.xxx.133:8080 weight=1; # low bandwith server
}
```

So, every 14 requests will go : 5 to xx.xx.xxx.130 and 131 servers, 3 to 132 and one to 133.

Read more: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_weighted_load_balancing

Comment: Sorry, I meant the server that I'm currently using as a load balancer is the one with the bandwidth problem. Not the 4 servers I purchased.